# Text messages sent from Outlook do not show in my Android's messaging folder

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sms, outlook, active-sync

I can send and receive text messages with my Outlook 2010 on an Exchange 2010 server.  Received text messages appear both on the phone and Outlook but sent text messages only appear on the device that sent it. (Outlook or the phone but not both)

I would like to see text message replies that are sent with Outlook in my phones messaging app with the original message that was received.  Can this be done?  I have a Samsung Galaxy S2.

Comment: Are you using the default messaging app?

Comment: Yes and would like to continue to if possible.

Comment: Text messages from Outlook? I'm confused, can you explain how you're doing that? Or do you mean emails?

Comment: Outlook 2010 with Exchange 2010 can send a text message (SMS) from the Outlook client or OWA when you have phone associated with the email account using Active Sync and you enabled the sync of SMS messages on the phone.

Comment: Better explanation can be found here.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/send-and-receive-text-messages-sms-HA101823438.aspx

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible as you have an Android phone. If you were on Windows mobile it might work to have your sent messages sync, but the default app will not do what you want it to do with Outlook.

Comment: Disappointing.  It is a nice feature to be able to send and receive text messages from the Outlook interface but if half of the conversation is missing when I go mobile and only have the phone with me then the benefits quickly diminish.  
I did find repeated references to Windows phones but was hoping the Android’s Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync feature was up to the task.  Anyone else have a suggestion or know a secret to get it to work?